# Struts 2 select and Distinct select items

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, hql

I have a `ArrayList` which of type `empDetail` (a POJO class).

```
List<EmpDetail> empDetailList = new ArrayList<EmpDetail>();
```

This list represents a table in the database.
I need values for a dropdown list and so I did

```jsp
<s:select list="empDetailList" listKey="country"  listValue="country" name="country"></s:select>
```

By this I get all rows of country column from database and its good. But I need unique country in this dropdown list.

I know I can write a SQL query to get distinct country, but how to do it in this kind of scenario.

**Update 1:**
Do any one of you have Hibernate solution for this?

**Update 2:**
 My POJO class as follows...

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;


public class EmpDetail implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long     id;
    private String   name;
    private int  age;
    private String   address;
    private String   city;
    private String   section;
    private String   country;
    private String   classStudying;
    private String   fatherName;
    private String   motherNmae;
    private Date     DOJ;
    private String   certificates;
    private Date     CompletedDate;
    private String   crossCheckedBy;
    private Date     crossCheckedDate;
    private String   comments;


    //and its getters and setters...


}
```

Comment: How do you populate your list?

Comment: @AleksandrM I have shown it in my question. I get the get all the column using `select * form empDetail` and then I store it in this arrayList.

Comment: So it is SQL query. Why not to use distinct?

Comment: @AleksandrM I need all the column and I am going to have dropdownlist for all the column. And what you have replied me was already I have mentioned it in my question about the DISTINCT.

Comment: Why not to write separate SQL query for retrieving just country list?

Comment: Convert list to the map.

Comment: @AleksandrM as I said earlier I am going to have dropdownlist for all the columns for the table form DB. so I try to find new way and not to use separate select query with distinct for each column, I here have 10 column to be listed. Do you have any Hibernate solutions?

Comment: @RomanC I can not get your point clear. Since my list is a representation of a table which has more than 10 column. what to do when we convert this list to map?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk: Iterate over `empDetail` and put columns to set, then use that set in `<s:select>` tag.

Comment: your list is representation of the Object as you stated in your question.

Comment: @RomanC yes and whats your doubt.?

Comment: What is the object, could you post the code?

Comment: @RomanC I have posted the object code.. its just a pojo class

Comment: @SathishKumarkk So, what did it solve your problem?

Comment: @RomanC I would like to get different possibilities of using struts2 or any feature in java that satisfy my scenario...

Comment: I like to know the reason why I was down voted... this down vote discourages me...

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by country objects. Simple HQL query

```
from EmpDetail where id in (select max(id) from EmpDetail group by country)
```

Comment: I need all the column at the same time?

Comment: @SathishKumarkk The query return a `Set<EmpDetail>` not `List<Object[]>`. Use accessors of EmpDetail for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display distinct select items means

```
 EmpDetail empDetail = new EmpDetail();
 Map<Object, Object> empDetailMap = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
    if (empDetailList.size() > 0) {
        for (Iterator<EmpDetail> iter = industryDetail.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            empDetail = (EmpDetail) iter.next();
            empDetailMap.put(empDetail.getId(),empDetail.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: No I dont have only one column to be displayed as dropdown list... I have the full table in the arrayList in this case what to do in the JSP page?